# Intro as Hidden #div. Stop Sound on Click

Tags: css, iframe, html

If you click the link below, you will find that when you play the intro video, and then click enter site, the audio still plays. Is there a way to kill the video onClick?

Thanks for any help.

Example:
http://www.kineticoriginsofrhythm.com/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding the div, remove it.  That will kill the video.

However, as Varazi mentioned, this is a pretty strange way to handle it.  Just link through :)